# juju credential error masage

Tags: juju, maas

```
Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.  Error details: no reachable servers.
Error: Unable to connect to environment "maas". Please check your credentials or use 'juju bootstrap' to create a new environment.
Error details: no reachable servers
```

I have 2 nodes are ready on maas server and when I run juju bootstrap one of them going to located to root user but I still got the error massage I mentioned above this my environment file,

```
environments:
  maas: 
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'maas-server-ip-address/MAAS'; 
    maas-oauth: 'vzgAAtkW9YftwMRDxb:z9EHbEgsBjMNjbP5r4:9AdTb7gMU39FvPBKHsbPYNT9FAtFGscs' 
    admin-secret: 'my-root-password'
    default-series: 'precise'
```

Edit:

The out put of juju bootstrap -v --debug it's too much but the end of output is:

```
WARNING juju.provider.maas environ.go:181 picked arbitrary tools &{"1.14.1-precise-amd64" "172.26.0.10:80/MAAS/api/1.0/files/…;} 
2013-09-26 13:06:41 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environ.go:267 maas user data; 9888 bytes 
2013-09-26 13:06:41 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environ.go:273 started instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-bb337654-25dc-11e3-ac82-70f39519a2c5/" 
2013-09-26 13:06:41 INFO juju supercommand.go:284 command finished
```

my environment file again is

```
environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: '172.26.0.10:80/MAAS/';
    maas-oauth: 'p3PeSub2ajPWVKL7pH:bZAWke8fydgAsBL8NQ:ZkZMjx5XvptMzrPgy2LqvA5W6BAWPCdj'
    admin-secret: 'admin-password'
    default-series: precise
    authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

My server's hostname is `hu` , and I think my problem is the admin password because I have read it has to be replaced with a random pass-phrase. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please run `juju destroy-environment`, then run `juju bootstrap -v --debug` and post the output of that command? Also, make sure your maas server is a FQDN, `http://mass-server-ip-address:80/MAAS` for example.

Comment: my environment file again is environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://172.26.0.10:80/MAAS/'
    maas-oauth: 'p3PeSub2ajPWVKL7pH:bZAWke8fydgAsBL8NQ:ZkZMjx5XvptMzrPgy2LqvA5W6BAWPCdj'
    admin-secret: 'admin-password'                     
    default-series: precise
    authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: the out put of juju bootstrap -v --debug it's too much but the end of output is ,,,,  WARNING juju.provider.maas environ.go:181 picked arbitrary tools &{"1.14.1-precise-amd64" "http://172.26.0.10:80/MAAS/api/1.0/files/?key=fed5aade-26aa-11e3-868b-10604b5bcfae&op=get_by_key"}
2013-09-26 13:06:41 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environ.go:267 maas user data; 9888 bytes
2013-09-26 13:06:41 DEBUG juju.provider.maas environ.go:273 started instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-bb337654-25dc-11e3-ac82-70f39519a2c5/"
2013-09-26 13:06:41 INFO juju supercommand.go:284 command finished

Comment: my server hostname is hu , and i think my problem in the admin password because i read it have to be replaced with a random pass-phrase , Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you please add this information into your question and not these comments? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I got a very similar error when I tried to bootstrap Juju when I had two nodes that were both in the "Allocated" state.  I had to "Stop" one of the two nodes, putting it into the "Ready" state and bootstrap again.  Not sure if that's your issue but it's something I ran into.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the semicolons at he ends of the lines.

Also, for the admin-secret, this is just going to be the password for various machines set up with Juju. Just set it to anything hard to guess.

On the `maas-server` line, you need to have a `http://` before it, making the while line something like

```
    maas-server: 'http://172.26.0.10/MAAS/'
```

The picked arbitrary tools message is fine, mine does that and has no ill effects.

Make sure you take the `maas-oauth` value from the MaaS web UI on the user preferences page (it calls it a key).

So, the whole `environments.yaml` file should look about like this:

```
environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://172.26.0.10/MAAS/'
    maas-oauth: 'p3PeSub2ajPWVKL7pH:bZAWke8fydgAsBL8NQ:ZkZMjx5XvptMzrPgy2LqvA5W6BAWPCdj'
    admin-secret: '5fjC6PPeO9XwrPu1TfNmMWD4q'
    default-series: precise
    authorized-keys-path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```